# Плавный переход от одного числа к другому в Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Необходимо написать метод, который будет в UI отображать плавный переход между двумя числами. Например, Label.Text = 45, и задано входное число 90. Нужно отобразить видимый переход от числа 45 к 90 на этом Label. Что-то схожее со счётчиком очков в играх.  Попробовал с использованием линейной интерполяции как это часто делают в Unity. Но что-то не вышло. Вот код:

```
    private void SmoothChange(float end, float duration)
    {
        float time = 1.0f;
        while (time < duration)
        {
            Result = Lerp(Result, end, time / duration);
            time += time * 0.5f;
        }
        Result = end;
    }

    float Lerp(float first, float second, float i)
    {
        return firstFloat * (1 - i) + secondFloat * i;
    }
```

Result - число 45, а переменная end хранит в себе число 90, если ссылаться на пример выше.

Comment: [Анимации](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/761867/animations-in-xamarin-and-xamarin-forms/) к вашим услугам. Насколько я помню, `DoubleAnimation` такое позволяет сделать, но не помню, есть ли оно в формах.

Comment: Ух ты. Изобретать велосипед - это конечно хорошо, но всё же лучше использовать уже готовое. Спасибо, @aepot.